# why am i getting an empty data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to read a tab-delimited file with pandas. I have used the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_folder/test.bed', sep='\t',header=0,index_col=0)
```

However, the resulting data frame is empty and looks something like this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [loc.00001  100   150, loc.00002   200    210 ..... ]
```

I wish to produce a data frame that includes a header present in this file.

```
             TSS           TES 
Loci         
loc.00001    100           150 
loc.00002    200           210
```

Any ideas why I am getting an empty data frame would be useful. Thank you.

Comment: Is separator `tab`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your separator is not `tab`, but `whitespace`, so need `sep='\s+'`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_folder/test.bed', sep='\s+',header=0,index_col=0)
```

Or use parameter `delim_whitespace`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_folder/test.bed', delim_whitespace=True, header=0,index_col=0)
```